# Git - Create a new branch with all the content from the master branch

Tags: git, git-branch

Say I have so far only worked on `master` and already pushed all the commits to the `master` branch on github.com. It is that simple to create a `testing` with all the content from `master` (at this specific point in time)?

```
$ git checkout -b testing
$ git add *
$ git push origin testing
```

Comment: The `add` is unneeded here. Just create and push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as RomainValeri says, it is not necessary the `git add *`
To create the testing branch, if you are in the master branch:

```
git checkout -b testing
```

To push your modifications to the branch testing:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Some message"
git push origin testing
```

Then, if your are want to merge what you have in testing to the master branch:

```
git checkout master
git merge testing
```